# Run a scheduled build using cc.net

Tags: c#, cruisecontrol.net, schedule

I am trying to schedule a build to be run at a scheduled time regardless of modifications. I would like to know if this is the correct way of Forcing a build and if there is a way to set cc.net to ignore modifications...

```
<triggers>
    <scheduleTrigger time="0500" buildCondition="ForceBuild" name="Scheduled">
        <weekDays>
            <weekDay>Tuesday</weekDay>
            <weekDay>Friday</weekDay>
        </weekDays>
    </scheduleTrigger>
</triggers>
```

I want to run builds at a designated time and day(not based on modifications).

Comment: Not sure I fully understand. You say you want to schedule it regardless of modifications but then you say you don't want it to build when modified. Can you clarify please?

Comment: @Scott - He doesn't want to build when the source changes. He only wants to build on a particular schedule. Think "nightly build".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing that I see that looks wrong here is, potentially, the way you have the time specified. In all the examples I've seen, it should be `time="05:00"` though I do understand that it is locale-dependent, so that may not actually be a problem.

Comment: Relavent link: http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Schedule+Trigger